# Find coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^n)^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you find the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^n)^3$?

Comment: The sum inside the brackets is $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Then the number you are looking for, using Taylor, is $f^{(50)}(0)/50!$ for $f(x)=(1-x)^{-3}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This is (for $|x|\lt 1$) equal to $\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}$. Do you know the expansion of $(1-x)^{-3}$ (general binomial theorem)? We want the coefficient of $x^{47}$.

Comment: how do you apply binomial theorem to a negative power?

Comment: You might want to look [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem). You may also have done the result in class as an application of "Stars and Bars."

Answer (score 4):

Another way to look at this is purely combinatorial: the number of integer solutions to:
$$a_1+a_2+a_3=50;\quad a_1,a_2,a_3>0.$$
(Or, equivalently, the number of ways to put 50 balls into 3 urns such that no urn is left empty.)

That number is well-known to be $\binom{50-1}{3-1}$.